# Error when flow imported

Tags: error, flow, microsoft-flow

I have two tenants. On one tenant I have my flow which is attached to SharePoint lists. I want to move this flow between tenants so I exported the flow from first tenant as zip file and I was trying to import this package to new tenant.
But every time I import this package this mysterious error occurs about `MultipleErrorsOccurred` and `BadRequest`.

I was trying to create new connection, assigning to old one from new tenant, but
every time I have the same error.

Is there any solution to that?

Or I must every time edit package with flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flow is attached to a specific list in a specific tenant, and your security context is derived from a particular user account in the first tenant. So exporting to another tenant won't work without some additional work to hook those back up.

Comment: yeah will be extra work but yes it's only way to make it work